# Как создать "вызыватель" функций в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

В стандартной кнопке юнити есть вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу повторить это в своём скрипте,но не знаю как это сделать.

Может кто знает как это сделать?(Ну или ссылку на гайд,я не нашел(()

Comment: UnityEvent.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ был найден с помощью пользователя [Yaroslav](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/352119/yaroslav).
Вот как это сделать:

```
public UnityEvent m_TestEvent;
```

Вызов функции осуществляется с  помощью:

```
 m_TestEvent.Invoke();
```

P.S. Не забудьте про `using UnityEngine.Events;`